# Comparison process with enum element values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enumeration

Enum A

```
{ a = 10, a1 = 35, ....}
```

Enum B

```
{ b = 5, b1 = 20, ..... }
```

How can I get the int values ​​of any two of the two enum class elements? To compare with these values ​​and destroy the smaller one.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  Maybe this is what you're looking for?

enumA.CompareTo(enumB) > 0 ? "A is greater than B" : "B is greater than or equal to A";
enumA.CompareTo(enumB) = 0 ? "A is equal to B" : "A is not equal to B";

This should compare two Enum instances (enumA and enumB), and execute the code inserted in place of the strings.

Comment: I mean type B
 To compare with type A, but find out which two items are and compare accordingly.

Comment: Sorry.  Maybe this is what you're looking for?  

enumA.CompareTo(enumB) > 0 ? "A is greater than B" : "B is greater than or equal to A";
enumA.CompareTo(enumB) = 0 ? "A is equal to B" : "A is not equal to B";

This should compare two Enum instances (enumA and enumB), and execute the code inserted in place of the strings.

Comment: yes that was what I wanted ..
I hope it makes comparisons between A and B in this way .. I'll try it thanks

Comment: If it works, do you mind accepting the answer as correct?  I'm trying to get enough reputation to add comments, and every little bit helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Take this console app as an example to obtain the lowest int from your enum type:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {

        enum Colors {
            blue = 1,
            orange = 2,
            purple = 3
        }

        enum Stages {
            level1 = 35,
            level2 = 62,
            level3 = 13
        }

        public static int getMinEnumValue(Type enumType) {
            Array values = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
            List<int> intList = ((int[])values).ToList();
            int minValue = intList.Min();

            return minValue;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int minStagegInt = getMinEnumValue(typeof(Stages));
            int minColorInt = getMinEnumValue(typeof(Colors));

            Console.WriteLine($"Min stage int: {minStagegInt}, which is: {Enum.GetName(typeof(Stages), minStagegInt)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Min color int: {minColorInt}, which is: {Enum.GetName(typeof(Colors), minColorInt)}");
            Console.ReadLine();

            //keyValue anonymous type
            var myInstance1 = new[] { new { a = 10 }, new { a = 35 }, new { a = 3 } };
            var myInstance2 = new[] { new { b = 5 }, new { b = 20 } };

            var minObject1 = myInstance1.ToList().OrderBy(elem => elem.a).FirstOrDefault();
            var minObject2 = myInstance2.ToList().OrderBy(elem => elem.b).FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine($"Min a instance1: {minObject1.ToString()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Min b instance2: {minObject2.ToString()}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        } 
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Once you are able to get your min, or apply the logic you wish to your enum type, you can destroy or do whatever you want to your obtained enumeration intance of your enum type.

Comment: thanks for the answer..
There are abstract classes in two separate scripts that I have created, I have added enum to these two and I use GameManager to destroy them, I do all the operations there and there is no static, just add what you wrote to GameManager except enum classes as public void.

  and I'd be grateful if you could write an if line that destroys the smaller one based on this example.

Comment: have you tried to use the `getMinEnumValue` method removing the `static` yourself. You can do that and place that logic wherever you want

Comment: However I would advice to update your answer to clarify if you would like to obtain the min from an `enum` of from an [anonymous typed class](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/abhikumarvatsa/anonymous-typed-classes-in-C-Sharp/#:~:text=MSDN%20Definition%3A%20Anonymous%20types%20provide,our%20application%20cannot%20access%20it.)

Comment: regarding your last comment please update the code with correct format in the question

Comment: find the updated answer in case you might be using anonymous typed classes instead of enums. For that case, take into account the it is convenient that you use arrays of the same anonymous type, with the variable named the same, this is always `a` or `b` instead of  `a0`, `a1` etc. Because the type of the element inside the collection is the same, but you are changing the value

Answer (score 0):

Enum can be cast to int

```
 EnumA valA = EnumA.a; //10
 EnumB valB = EnumB.b; //5

 if((int)valA < (int)valB) // 10 < 5
 { Destroy(a);}
 else {Destroy(b);}
```

Edit:

```
public static int CompareAtoB(int a, int b)
{
     if(a==b) return 0;
     return (a < b) ? 1 : -1;
 }
```

You can now pass any value that you cast when you give as parameter.

```
int result = CompareAtoB((int)someEnum, (int) otherEnum);
```

Then act based on result.

Comment: So do I need to open the same operation with separate if blocks for c and d or e and f, or is there a more practical way to do this?